# Get LVM size using AWK?

Tags: linux, regex, awk, lvm, string

I'm in need to find out the LVM size of image `vm001`. Let's say I have a LVM volume called `/dev/VGgroup/vm001`. Now using `lvdisplay` I can find out the size:

```
--- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/VGgroup/vm001
  VG Name                VGgroup
  LV UUID                i0aYKs-Hpfv-q64V-9Rqu-6Wrq-eV3C-pZzo0D
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
  LV Size                25.00 GB
  Current LE             6400
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:41
```

How can I find out the LV size using a script/command which will output just `25`? I know with `awk` you can find strings horizontally, but not vertically (as far as I know).

**Edit**
There are more Logical Volumes, using `lvdisplay | awk '/LV Size/ { print $3 }'` will output all sizes (obviously), how do I only get the size of the volume I want to? (in this case `vm001`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a variable(`found`) in `awk`, and exit immediately after printing out `LV Size`.

```
$ lvdisplay | awk '/vm001/{found=1}; /LV Size/ && found{print $3; exit}'
25.00
```

- if **`vm001`** is found, then set **`found`** to **`1`** (because we known **`LV Size`** is following this line)
- if **`LV Size`** and **`found!=0`**, then print column#3, and **`exit`** immediately.

Comment: Thank you, this works like a charm! However could you eleborate your command a bit? I don't understand exactly what it does, trying to learn a bit aswell ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your edit, I now know exactly how it works. Cheers!

Comment: @Devator, @kev, just my 2 cents, you might want to protect the `/vm001/` from false-postitives (like `vm0012`) with say, `/vm001$/` or something.

Answer (score 6):

With

```
lvs /dev/vg/lvname -o LV_SIZE --noheadings --units G --nosuffix
```

you get the size of your LV in useful form.

Comment: Your answer is better to get the size without parsing and I think using `--units g` gives what user wants.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to select lines using '//' prefix for a block. For e.g on your lvdisplay output.

```
awk '/LV Size/ { print $3 }'
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. However there are more Logical Volumes, using `lvdisplay | awk '/LV Size/ { print $3 }'` will output all sizes (obviously), how do I only get the size of the volume I want to? (in this case `vm001`. Please refer to the table in my original post.

Comment: Ah. I'd have done it the way @kev suggested as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can also ask `lvs` for the information directly:

```
lvs vm001 --nosuffix --units g -o size --no-headings
```

or more specifically,

```
lvs VGgroup/vm001 --nosuffix --units g -o size --no-headings
```